# web scrap twitter following list of users with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter

i am trying to web scrap twitter following list by users example 
https://twitter.com/AzGoneClr/following
the function load the page, log in with cookies, then scroll down till the array stop growing in size
i run in to a problem where it get stuck on loading as i scroll down 
i tryd to focus elements on the page
clicking on home and after going back 
and this still stuck on loading
anyone know how to by pass this?

using: selenium undetected_chromedriver

```
def fetch_data(owneraddress: str):
        options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
        options.headless = False
        driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
        driver.set_window_size(400, 400)
    
     
        driver.get("{}/following".format(owneraddress))
        
        time.sleep(3)
        cururl=driver.current_url
        if 'following' not in cururl:
            driver.add_cookie({'name': 'auth_token','value':'{}'.format(config.twitter_auth)})
            driver.get("{}/following".format(owneraddress))
            time.sleep(3)
        
        pagescrollindex=100
    
        arrlist=[]
        lastcount=0
        endcount=0
        while True:
            
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {}-200)".format(pagescrollindex))
            time.sleep(0.1)
            pagescrollindex+=200
            htmlpage=driver.page_source
            if 'Hmm... this page doesn’t exist. Try searching for something else.' in htmlpage:
                return []
    
    
            test=htmlpage.split('"cellInnerDiv"')
    
            
            for x in test:
                if '</html>' in x:
                    continue
                username=''
                test3=x.split('aria-label="Follow @')
                if len(test3)<2:
                    continue
    
                #for y in test2:
    
                    #if y[0]=='/':
                        #print("found")
                        #username=y.split('"')[0]
                        #break
                username=test3[1].split('"')[0]
                if len(username)==0:
                    continue
    
                if username not in arrlist:
                    arrlist.append(username)
                else:
                    continue
                #print(username)
            if lastcount==len(arrlist):
                endcount+=1
            else:
                endcount=0
                lastcount=len(arrlist)
            if endcount==40:
                if 'class="css-1dbjc4n r-o52ifk"' not in test[-1]: # trying to check if got to last cell if not go to home page and back to try and break the stuck loading problem didnt work
                    endcount=0
                    #row=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'css-1dbjc4n')
                    home_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//a[contains(@href,"/home")]')
    
                    #home_link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Home")
    
                    home_link.click()
                    time.sleep(10)
                    driver.back()
                    time.sleep(10)
    
                    continue
    
                else:
                    break
        
        #if len(arrlist)<14:
            #state = driver.execute_script("return document.readyState")
            #print()
        driver.close()
        return arrlist
```